# Converting DLL offset to method name

Tags: gratis, windows-7, software-development, debugging

**Background**

My Java program crashed and I got a Java crash report. However, the crash was within JNI native code, so the crash log is not very useful, I'd better have a crash dump. The only useful information is the offset in my native DLL.

Extract of the Java crash report:

```
C  [test.dll+0x1032]
```

Since the crash is not easily reproducible, I cannot create a .dmp file, but still want to figure out which method was called.

**Tool request**

I am looking for a tool which would load an arbitrary PDB file, I enter the offset and the tool converts it to the method name + offset within the method.

```
Input:  test.dll+0x1032
Output: test.dll!mymethod+0x2A
```

**Requirements**

- Runs on Windows 7 x64
- Deals with PDB version 2.0 and 7.0
- preferred gratis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this can be done with WinDbg (part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)) like this:

1. Open the executable or DLL **as dump file** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), not as executable
2. `.symfix;.reload` to load the PDB, `.sympath+ <path>` if you need your own symbols
3. `ln <address>` to resolve the method name (e.g. `ln test.dll+0x1032`)

This is an answer because:

- WinDbg runs on Windows 7 x64/x86 (e.g. version 6.2.9200 / 6.3.9600)
- WinDbg loads arbitrary PDBs
- is available for free